# TextChanged Event for Textblock in WindowsStoreApps

Tags: wpf, events, windows-8, windows-store-apps, textblock

In `WindowsStoreApps` is there a `TextChanged` Event for `Textblock` or any thing similar as we have for `Textbox` (In `WindowsPhone`,I used `TextCompositionEventHandler`).
The Exact thing, I need is whenever a value is added to the `Textblock` an event should fire to get the values in the `TextBlock`(each time a value is added).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextBlock` does not provide for user editing of text content, as it is just a lightweight control to display text (in windows store as in windows phone). Since its content can only be changed programmatically, there will be no event raised on change. You can see the events on `TextBlock` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.aspx#memberListEvents). In Windows Store apps there is also still a `TextBox` control for user-editable text. This [has a `TextChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.aspx#memberListEvents).

If you really need to know when the `Text` property is updated, you can set up a binding to that dependency property. You can create your own custom dependency property with change handler which provides you notification:

```
class MyClass {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(MyClass), typeof(string), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnMyTextChanged));

    public static void OnMyTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Then you need to bind the property somewhere:

```
// myObj something of type MyClass
obj.SetBinding(textBlock, new Binding { Source = myObj, Path = new PropertyPath("MyText") });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Already I am using Textblock as customized textbox in my App.Can you give me much more details or any tutorial on binding to dependency property.

Comment: Updated to show example of using this kind of binding. Creating and binding to a dependency property should be covered on any book on Windows Store apps. MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh920267.aspx